# Enable readonly textbox after saving changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, readonly

I have some form which is editable in the same page. First attribute for each textbox is readonly, and when I press the edit button, it will become editable, using this syntax

```
$('input[readonly="readonly"]').removeAttr("readonly").prop("enabled",true);
```

when i press the save button, i want it become readonly again. I've trying to change it to

```
 $('input[readonly="readonly"]').attr("readonly").prop("disable",true);
  and
 $('input[readonly="readonly"]').attr("readonly").prop("readonly",true);
```

*but it won't change into readonly again.*

Is there any proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

readonly attributes was removed when you press the edit button.

so, `$('input[readonly="readonly"]')` doesn't match anything.

---

For example,

`$('input[type="text"]').attr("readonly", "readonly");`

will set all textboxes to readonly.

Comment: @randytan if you want to specify the textbox. you need set class, name or id to target textboxes.

Comment: Check my answer, maybe you want to add an ID for your textbox and use that to select. Choosing the selectors depends on your HTML

Comment: okay, i just use type="text" and it works. I prefer not to add additional ids or name to make it disable, because, in my page there are more than 100 text inputs. thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

you need to

```
$('<your-selector>').prop("disable",true).attr("readonly", "readonly");
```

because calling `.attr("readonly")` just returns the value of the attribute `readonly`, here you need to set the `readonly` property value for that you need to pass two arguments to [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-value)

Comment: what do you mean by selector? it is just input? because there are a lot input ids. So i just need to place "input" only? thanks

Comment: @randytan how to identify your target input element, does it have a name/id/class

Comment: yes it has ids and name. but every input type has different ids and name. Is there any way to make it one hit kill? :D

Comment: add a common class attribute to all the target elements

Answer (score 0):

In `$('input[readonly="readonly"]').attr("readonly").prop("disable",true);`, the selector that you are using is looking for an input that is already readOnly  I don't think that you want to make a readOnly input readOnly.

Give it an ID or find another way to select it then do `$("#myInput").attr("disabled", "disabled")`. Tested on chrome.